# In Python Flask, how to access complete raw URL prior to un-escaping

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

I see Flask provides a few [parsed fields](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Request.path) in Request, however the url is after removing escapes. Any way to access the url prior to un-escaping done by Flask?

For example when a rest client makes request for "http://www.example.com/my_url%20is%20here?arg1=2&?arg2=3", Flask provides me with the request.base_url of "http://www.example.com/my_url is here" where %20 is replaced with spaces. I can quote this myself to get the original URL as someone responded, but preferably I would like to access the original URL as it was sent by the client rather than deriving it.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to accomplish this without encoding request.url manually. It looks like werkzeug discards a raw url encoding. For me this issue is a major problem where clients use path and query string values inside of HMAC signature.

Comment: This is quite old, but I ran into this problem for the same reason as @Boris.
All the other solutions is problematic when the request path is part of a signature, as the exact pre-decoded characters are required.
There is a workaround if your app is running under gunicorn or uwsgi: https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/pull/1419/files#diff-2fd07ed8a4cc8c956ceeca2347ac5376
Basically need middleware to inject the raw path.
I created one that precisely does that:
https://gist.github.com/coderfi/06b1f8fea7fd8ed37aa171bff5fc11e2

Hope it helps others.

Answer (score 6):

The fields are not [URLs, or even URIs](https://danielmiessler.com/study/url_vs_uri/), they are [IRI](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3987)s. Use `iri_to_uri`:

```
from werkzeug.urls import iri_to_uri
iri_to_uri(request.url)
```

From [werkzeug/wrappers.py](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/wrappers.py):

```
"""
...
Note that the string returned might contain unicode characters as the
representation is an IRI not an URI.  If you need an ASCII only
representation you can use the :func:`~werkzeug.urls.iri_to_uri`
function:
>>> from werkzeug.urls import iri_to_uri
>>> iri_to_uri(get_current_url(env))
'http://localhost/script/?param=foo'
...
"""
```

One of the nice things about flask and werkzeug is that you can always follow things through in the source code.

Answer (score -2):

You mean %XX escapes?

```
from urllib.parse import quote

quote(url)
```